# "window.innerWidth < 768" in Next.js with Framer Motion

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, framer-motion

I would like to control when an animation (Framer Motion) can run using `window.innerWidth`, but in Next.js I get the following error message:

`ReferenceError: window is not defined`

This is a simplified version of my component named ValuesSection.jsx:

```js
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { useInView } from "react-intersection-observer";
import { motion, useAnimation } from "framer-motion";

export default function ValuesSection() {
  const controls = useAnimation();
  const [ref, inView] = useInView();
  const MobileView = {};
  const isMobile = window.innerWidth < 768;
  if (!isMobile) {
    MobileView = {
      visible: { y: 0, scale: 1 },
      hidden: { y: 250, scale: 0 },
    };
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    if (inView) {
      controls.start("visible");
    }
  }, [controls, inView]);

  return (
<>
 <motion.div
  key={value.name}
  ref={ref}
  animate={controls}
  initial="hidden"
  variants={MobileView}
 >Some content</motion.div>
</>
```

Can you help me understand what I'm doing wrong? And if you are able to provide me with a working example, it would be great and appreciated.

Comment: Next.js runs in a node environment where there is no `window` object. The first time this code is run is on the server side, not in the browser. The earliest you can access the `window` in a React component created with Next.js is inside a `useEffect`.

Comment: Alright. Good to know. Can you show me an example based of my code provided? I'm not quite sure how to implement it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Best way of using screen size in next.js projects is that you can instead use a Hook from `materiial ui` that represents true or false when screen width is bigger or smaller than defined value and in my opinion it's better than the `window` because it has a lot of options that you can use here is what you should do step by step

first install material ui if you didn't already

```
// with npm
npm install @material-ui/core

// with yarn
yarn add @material-ui/core
```

then import and define it inside of your component

```
import { useMediaQuery } from "@material-ui/core";


export default function ValuesSection() {

const IsTabletOrPhone = useMediaQuery("(max-width:1024px)");
```

now if you screen size is bigger than `1024px` it returns `false`, otherwise it returns `true`
so you can use it

```
  if (!IsTabletOrPhone) {
    MobileView = {
      visible: { y: 0, scale: 1 },
      hidden: { y: 250, scale: 0 },
    };
  }
```

## Update:

Maybe it's because i assigned it with a uppercase letter, you can try changing the name to `isTabletOrPhone`  with lowercase, if that didn't work try to change it to `let` instead

```
let isTabletOrPhone = useMediaQuery("(max-width:1024px)");
```

Comment: Great solution. Really simple implementation.

It does give me the following error message now: `TypeError: Assignment to constant variable.`

Comment: I updated the answer, check the end of it and tell me the result.

Comment: Thanks! I figured out, that it was complaining about `const MobileView = {};`, so I changed that to `let`, and it worked. 

But now since I disabled the animation on smaller screen, the content never appears. From one issue to another.

Comment: Oh ok, i'm glad to help. if possible you can add create a codesandbox where i can see the code and check if i can solve the new problem, or you can ask another question on stackoverflow and see if the others can help you.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/nextjs-framer-motion-issue-fms55?file=/components/ValuesSection.jsx

Here you go. I tried to get as close to production as possible. Remember to minimise the terminal in Codesandbox, and refresh between screen/window sizes.

Comment: installing materialUI just to get screen size doesn't seem a very good solution to me.

Answer (score -2):

In Next.js pages are prerendered on the server. And on the server there's no window. You could just check if the window exists before to access it

```js
const isMobile = global.window && window.innerWidth < 768;
```

Note that the user may rotate the phone or resize the window, so you should add (and clean up) a [resize](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/resize_event) event handler into an `useEffect`